# How to toggle hide and unhide sensitive information in kubernetes and kibana logs that comes from spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, kibana, slf4j

I have a spring boot app that logs sensitive information in the kubernetes and kibana.
How do I create a flag to toggle hide/unhide sensitive information ?
This sensistive information can be used only for debugging purposes.

I am looking for something like :

- isMaskEnabled = false :
  set this flag only for debugging purposes so that developers can use it for debugging.
- isMaskEnabled = true :
  set this flag for masking sensitive information to all users who views the logs.

I tried setting the appender slf4j - to have mask pattern but that will log the information as masked fields in log file. I can't see original data for debugging purposes.

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
    <layout class="com.bpcbt.micro.utils.PatternMaskingLayout">
        <maskPattern>creditCard=\d+</maskPattern> <!-- SourcePan pattern -->
        <pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%ex</pattern>-->
    </layout>
</encoder>
```

If I want to unmask and show original info it is not possible here.
Any other way ?

Comment: Step 1 is to never log sensitive info to the logs.

Comment: Step 1: remove all code that logs actual credit cards numbers in a context where they might learn more about who those belong to? Change your log statements to only log, say, the last 4 digits, but ideally, _don't log credit card numbers_.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
Now If I want to debug, I go through those logs it will have only 4 digits, 
I need to find the way to get original data for debugging purposes. 
I wanted to check the sensistive information as developer and hide it for common people who query through kibana.

Comment: If you can find actual credit card numbers tied to actual people, there's every chance you're already breaking local laws around handling PII. Find a different way to identify transactions that doesn't require PII such as randomly generated transaction numbers, and look for _those_ in your logs.

Comment: Why not control logs in Spring boot/java module? Eg. You can have a public function that logs all info you need. Then use isMaskEnabled to enable or disable logging. Probably enable during development and disable logging when deploying to production